# AWS Appsync query with in or not in operator doesn't exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I want to return all items that are not in my arrays. Some think like below but in graphql-aws world:

```
query(
collection(db, "users"),
where("id", "not-in", [...likedUserIds, ...dislikedUserIds])
)
```

I tried:

```
const { data } = await API.graphql(
graphqlOperation(getUsers, {
filter: { id: { ne: [...likedUserIds, ...dislikedUserIds]} },
})
);
```

But this says "Variable 'ne' has an invalid value.", How can I implement my query? nin or in not a valid operator for appsync